# How to get counts of occurrences from two tables

Tags: mysql, sql, count

I have two tables: `Items` and `Things`. Items `has_many` things

Items

```
id     name
----   -----
1      Item1
2      Item2
```

Things

```
id     name    item_id
----  -----  -----------
1     thing1   1
2     thing2   1
3     thing3   1
4     thing6   2
5     thing7   6
6     thing6   2
```

I would like a result back mathing all rows from items with things and getting count based on `item_id`

```
id    name   count
---   ----  ------
1     item1  3
2     item2  2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT i.id,i.name,count(*)
FROM items i
INNER JOIN things t ON t.item_id = i.id
GROUP BY i.id, i.name
ORDER BY i.id
```